# Suppose $a, b, c$ are integers. Prove that if $a^2+b^2=c^2$, then $a$ or $b$ is even

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Suppose $a, b, c$ are integers. Prove that if $a^2+b^2=c^2$, then $a$ or $b$ is even.

I planned on doing a proof by contrapositive, making the new proof "If $a$ and $b$ are odd, then $a^2+b^2 \ne c^2.$"

We can then make $a=2k+1$, where $k$ is an integer, and $b=2j+1$ where $j$ is an integer.

I've gone through and done 2 cases for c. Testing it as odd and even.

Comment: **Hint :** Think modulo $4$.

Comment: So, ..., you have two choices for $c$: $2\ell$ and $2\ell+1$.  Put that in, notice you have a *lot* of $4$s, so reduce modulo $4$.  Now what?

Comment: Your plan is correct. If you sub that in, you will find that c^2 = 2 + a multiple of four. Then, as in the other suggestions, see what happens if c is even and then if c is odd.

Comment: The only squares modulo four are zero and one.